# using will and will be in proper places

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, future-tense

I have confusion in a sentence.

If restaurants sell pizza, their sales will double.

or, If restaurants sell pizza, their sales will be doubled.

1. `Will / will be` which one is correct and why?
2. `their sales` why we use verb(sale)+s? Although the subject is restaurants which is clearly a plural form of restaurant.

Thank you.

Comment: For the "active" hypothetical / future tense *(**their sales will double**)* only the "unmarked infinitive" *(**double**)* is syntactically valid. Alternatively, there's the "adjectival" version *(their sales will **be** double* - adjectivally describing the future state of sales). OR the "passive" version *(their sales will be **doubled**)* - where the Past Participle specifies ***what will be done to sales*** (by the act of selling pizza).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "sale" is a noun in this context, meaning the event of selling something - in this specific context it refers in a general way to the money made from the sale, i.e. "Sales" means "the total amount of money made from all of the sales".

> Sales will double. ("double" is a verb)

This refers to the process of that amount doubling, more transactions/sales, etc.

> Sales will be double. ("double" is an adjective)

This refers to the fact that the end result/amount will be double ("twice as much as") what it would have been.